# Строка в массив

Tags: c++builder

Есть строка:

```
AnsiString xx;
xx="1-2-1-1";
```

(элементы разделены через тире)

Как записать в динамический массив элементы (только по одному разу) т.е. 1 и 2.
Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Вообще такое решается через ассоциативные массивы. В с++ есть библиотека <map>, думаю в билдере тоже есть. Но это конечно не самая легкая задача для двух крестов.

Comment: Кажется пример:

http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map

Comment: Что-то мне в этом *помогите* видится *напишите мне код*... @SilverIce, в бусте есть, а буст есть в новом быдлере (хотя map  далеко не ассоциативный массив)